# Bunny & Probability, How to solve this probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Two boxes, $X$ and $Y$, each box contains two bunnies, let $x_w$ be the white bunny in box $X$,and let $x_b$ be the black bunny in box $X$. Similarly, $y_w$ be the white bunny in box $Y$ and $y_b$ be the black bunny in box $Y$.

We define the **operation** as: Simultaneously taking one bunny from $X$, and taking one bunny from $Y$, then interchange them to the other box. For example, initially, we have $X=(x_w, x_b), Y=(y_w, y_b)$, if we choose $x_w$ from $X$, and $y_b$ from $Y$, after this operation, we get $X=(y_b, x_b), Y=(y_w, x_w)$.

After we do this **operation** by $n$ times, what is the probability that each box still contains one white bunny and one black bunny? (Not necessarily to be the original bunnies in boxes.)

My attempt:

If we define $P_n$ as the probability after $n$ operations. For $n=1$, we have totally four cases, here we only need to look at one box, say box $X$, since $Y$ is automatically settled once $X$ is settled. After the first operation, box $X$ could be $(y_w, x_b), (y_b, x_b), (x_w, y_w), (x_w, y_b)$, so we know $P_1=2/4$

After two operations, each of above four cases will generate another four subcases, totally $16$ subcases, and some of them are repeated, by counting, I get $P_2=12/16$

But how to derive a general formula for $P_n$?

**Update**

Thank you for your help, and I can understand this problem now. But I have another question. (Should I ask here or put in a new question?) @A.J. uses the three term homogeneous equation, but @Mathfail uses two term inhomogeneous equation, and both give the same result. Is there a more deep connection between the two methods? Can I say, algebraically, the three term homogeneous equation is equivalent to two term inhomogeneous equation?

Comment: I feel the operation could be represented as a Markov process, with the probability distribution changing from $x_n$ to $x_{n+1} = A x_n$. Then $x_n = A^n x_0$, and $P_n$ could be obtained from that. Though I'm not experienced enough to know how to construct the vectors and matrices

Answer (score 3):

As you stated in the question, the contents of one of the boxes always determines the contents of the other, so we need only focus on one of the boxes' contents.

Define $B_n$ to be the probability that after $n$ operations the box contains cats of both colors, and $S_n$ to be the probability that after $n$ operations the box contains cats of only a single color.

Let's consider $B_n$ first. In order for the box to contain cats of both colors after the $n$th operation, then after the $(n-1)$st operation, either the box had cats of both colors, and the two subsequently switched cats had the same color (which happens with probability $\frac{1}{2}$); or the box had cats of a single color, and the subsequently switched cats had different colors (which happens with certainty, i.e. probability $1$). This leads to the recursion

$$B_n = \frac{1}{2} B_{n-1} + S_{n-1}$$

On the other hand, considering $S_n$, the only way for the box to contain cats of a single color following the $n$th switch is for it to have contained cats of both colors after the $(n-1)$st switch and for the subsequently switched cats to have different colors (which happens with probability $\frac{1}{2}$). Thus we have the recursion

$$S_n = \frac{1}{2} B_{n-1}$$

The latter can be rewritten as $S_{n-1} = \frac{1}{2} B_{n-2}$; then substituting this into the first equation and eliminating fractions yields

$$2B_n = B_{n-1} + B_{n-2}$$

The characteristic equation for this recursion is $2x^2 = x + 1$ which has solutions $x=-\frac{1}{2},1$ so the solution for $B_n$ will have the form

$$B_n = \alpha (1)^n + \beta \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)^n$$

Noting that $B_0 = 1$ and $B_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ gives us the system

$$\begin{align}
\alpha + \beta &= 1 \\[2mm]
\alpha - \frac{1}{2} \beta &= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$

which has solutions $\alpha = \frac{2}{3}$ and $\beta = \frac{1}{3}$. Thus the answer we're looking for is

$$B_n = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3} \left( -\frac{1}{2} \right)^n$$

Comment: Thank you, can I ask the difference for the three term recursion and two term recursion? You use the three term homogeneous equation, but @Mathfail uses two term inhomogeneous equation, and both give the same result. Is there more deep connection between the two methods? Can I say, algebraically, the three term homogeneous equation is equivalent to two term inhomogeneous equation?

Comment: I'm not sure there's an answer to that. Mathfail and I both used recursions, we just had different approaches to the problem. There may be a way to establish a connection between the two, but I think it's more important to understand that both are valid approaches, because there may be situations where one of the methods may not work as well as the other, so understanding both gives you more options.

Comment: I see, I think I understand both methods now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

After the first operation, you get

> $(y_w, x_b), (y_b, x_b), (x_w, y_w), (x_w, y_b)$

After the second operation, for each case, it will split into another 4 subcases. Let $O_n$ be the n-th operation, the total cases are: $$1\xrightarrow{O_1}4\xrightarrow{O_2}4^2\rightarrow\dots \xrightarrow {O_n}4^n$$

The probability $$P_n=\frac{A_n}{4^n}$$

Next, let's count $A_n$, which means after n-th operation, how many cases are "white & black" bunnies in box $X$. We try to derive $A_n$ by $A_{n-1}$. Let's define: "favor" means opposite color bunnies in box $X$, "non-favor" means same color bunnies in box $X$. After (n-1)-th operation, we get

$$P_{n-1}=\frac{A_{n-1}}{4^{n-1}}$$

There are $A_{n-1}$ cases are favored, and $(4^{n-1}-A_{n-1})$ are non-favor.

Key observation is: for each non-favor case, i.e. (white, white), no matter which bunny you choose and interchange with box $Y$, it will lead to 4 subcases such that all of them are favored cases, namely, opposite color. However, for each favor case, i.e. (white, black), after one operation, half of them become favor cases, half of them become non-favor cases. Let's see this by an example,

$(y_w, x_b)$ is a favored case, after one operation, it splits into

$$(y_b, x_b), (x_w, x_b), (y_w, x_w), (y_w, y_b)$$

where half of them become favor cases ($(x_w, x_b), (y_w, y_b)$), half of them become non-favor cases ($(y_b, x_b), (y_w, x_w)$). Therefore, we can get the recurence equation:

$$A_n=2A_{n-1}+4(4^{n-1}-A_{n-1})$$

Simplify and we get

$$A_n=-2A_{n-1}+4^{n}, ~~~A_1=2$$

Solve this first order inhomogeneous recurrence equation, we get

$$A_n=\frac{1}3\cdot(-2)^n+\frac{2}3\cdot 4^n$$

The probability is:

$$\boxed{P_n=\frac{2}3+\frac{1}3\cdot \left( \frac{-1}2\right)^n}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For $x \in \{0, 1, 2\}$, let $p_n(x)$ be the probability that after $n$ operation the box $X$ contains $x$ white bunnies.

$$p_0(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x = 1$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Now for $n\ge 1$

$$p_n(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}p_{n-1}(x+1) & \text{if $x = 0$}\\
p_{n-1}(x-1) + \frac12p_{n-1}(x) + p_{n-1}(x+1) & \text{if $x = 1$}\\
\frac{1}{4}p_{n-1}(x-1)& \text{if $x = 2$}
\end{cases}$$

So $\boldsymbol p_n = \begin{bmatrix}p_n(0)\\ p_n(1)\\ p_n(2)\end{bmatrix}$ then $$\boldsymbol p_n = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \frac14 & 0\\ 1 & \frac12 & 1\\0 & \frac14 & 0\end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol p_{n-1}$$ and so $$\boldsymbol p_n = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \frac14 & 0\\ 1 & \frac12 & 1\\0 & \frac14 & 0\end{bmatrix}^n \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\boldsymbol A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \frac14 & 0\\ 1 & \frac12 & 1\\0 & \frac14 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ are

- $\lambda_1=1$ and $\boldsymbol u_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 4\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$
- $\lambda_2=-\frac12$ and $\boldsymbol u_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ -2\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$
- $\lambda_3=0$ and $\boldsymbol u_3 = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\ 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

Since $$\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \frac16 \boldsymbol u_1 - \frac16 \boldsymbol u_2$$

Then $$\boldsymbol p_n = \frac16 \lambda_1^n \boldsymbol u_1 - \frac16\lambda_2^n \boldsymbol u_2$$

Finally,

$$p_n(1) = \frac16 \left(4 + 2\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right) = \frac13\left(2+\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, and could please explain why this one works...$$p_n(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4}p_{n-1}(x+1) & \text{if $x = 0$}\\
p_{n-1}(x-1) + \frac12p_{n-1}(x) + p_{n-1}(x+1) & \text{if $x = 1$}\\
\frac{1}{4}p_{n-1}(x-1)& \text{if $x = 2$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: What is the probability of going from $0$ bunnies to $1$ bunny?

Comment: It might be clearer to express it as: $$\qquad p_n(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{4}p_{n-1}(1) & \text{if }x = 0\\ p_{n-1}(0) + \frac12p_{n-1}(1) + p_{n-1}(2) & \text{if }x = 1\\ \frac{1}{4}p_{n-1}(1)& \text{if }x = 2\end{cases}$$

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand why to introduce $x$... it is possible to only use $p_n$ to compute?

Comment: What is the definition of $p_n$ if you don't introduce $x$?